# Play! Framework async calls modifying same object of database

Tags: web-services, postgresql, asynchronous, akka, playframework-2.2

I have several questions about this code :

```
public static Result submit() {

        final Object object = filledForm.get();

        Akka.future(new Callable<Void>() {
            public Void call() throws Exception {
                 WS1...
                 object.save();
            });

        Akka.future(new Callable<Void>() {
            public Void call() throws Exception {
                 WS2...
                 object.save();
            });

        return ok(....);
}
```

1. Akka.future is deprecated, I should use Promise as explained [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/Migration22)
   .It's more verbose. How do you do ?
2. This cause optimistic lock exceptions because of parallel writings in database.
   Should I encapsulate calls in one another ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you any insight ?

Comment: As you have coded this right now, the calls will be happening concurrently which could indeed result in both of them trying to write to the db at the same time.  If there is an actual sequence here, and you want one to happen after another then you need to chain them together.  In Scala, this would be done with `map` or `flatMap`.  Not sure if these constructs exist in the Java world...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you save the object updates after both calls are done you avoid altogether the locking issues. So you can group together your calls using Promise like this:

```
public static Promise<Result> submit() {
final Object object = filledForm.get();
Promise<JsonNode> jsonPromise1 = ws.url("url1").get().map(
    new Function<WSResponse, JsonNode>() {
        public JsonNode apply(WSResponse response) {
            JsonNode json = response.asJson();
            return json;
        }
    }
);
Promise<JsonNode> jsonPromise2 = ws.url("url2").get().map(
    new Function<WSResponse, JsonNode>() {
        public JsonNode apply(WSResponse response) {
            JsonNode json = response.asJson();
            return json;
        }
    }
);
 return Promise.sequence(jsonPromise1,jsonPromise2).map(
 new Function<WSResponse, Result>() {
        public JsonNode apply(List<JsonNode> results) {
            //populate object
           object.save();
            return ok(...);
        }
    });
}
```

if you need to rely on the information from the first call to make the second one, you can chain the promises together like `return promise1.flatMap(){ return promise2.map { object.save()}}`

Do not forget to add a recover function, in case your calls may fail.

For a full example take a look at https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaWS , if you are using an older version of play just replace 2.4.x with your version prefix.

Answer (score 0):

1. In this example it doesn't look like you're waiting for futures to complete; assuming you really don't need to, promises are not more verbose because you can ignore the returned promise and just return from your method as you're doing here. The only difference is in API names: "Callable" becomes "Function0" and "call" becomes "apply".
2. It depends if they are part a logical sequence of if they really are independent and should run concurrently. If the first applies then yes, you should abstract the bodies into local methods and call them in a sequence, else it's correct to have them run concurrently. In this case you can either live with optimistic locking and perform a retry (user-triggered, which is perhaps more common for optimistic locking, or automatic, depending on your situation) or change to pessimistic locking and isolation levels (which might affect negatively your performances as it resorts most often to DB-level locks and so higher resource contention).